# ICS-10064: An error occurred while preparing mapper object: Invalid element 'complexType' in 'element'

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I wrote the following xml-schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/nxsd/surrogate/request"
           xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/nxsd/surrogate/request"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Building">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="content">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Floor" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="attribute">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="Square" type="xs:integer"/>
                        <xs:element name="Height" type="xs:integer"/>
                        <xs:element name="Rooms" type="xs:integer" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However, when running this, it results in an error message `Invalid element 'complexType' in 'element'`

[image]

Does anybody know what's going on here?

UPDATE
Here is the error stack trace that I have downloaded from OIC

```
<Jan 28, 2021, 2:18:47,612 AM UTC> <Error> <oracle.apps.oic.integration.jetmapper> <BEA-000000> <TX_MULTI_ERRORGUI_MM_ERR_SRC_SCHEMA'Invalid element 'complexType' in 'element''> 
<Jan 28, 2021, 2:18:47,616 AM UTC> <Error> <oracle.ics.webconsole> <ICS-10064> <An error occurred while preparing mapper object.
oracle.ics.webconsole.common.exception.GeneralException: ICS-10064: An error occurred while preparing mapper object.
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.TransformerElement.validateModel(TransformerElement.java:194)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.OrchestrationModelImpl.validateElements(OrchestrationModelImpl.java:1211)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.OrchestrationModelImpl.updateElement(OrchestrationModelImpl.java:1190)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.view.beans.backing.orchestration.ReceiveBeanElement.updateElement(ReceiveBeanElement.java:390)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.view.beans.backing.composer.OrchestrationBean.onConfirmEditAdapter(OrchestrationBean.java:1655)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.view.beans.backing.composer.OrchestrationPageBean.confirmEditAdapter(OrchestrationPageBean.java:1668)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6131.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)


Caused By: oracle.apps.oic.integration.jetmapper.model.exception.JETMapperExceptionV2: Invalid element 'complexType' in 'element'
    at oracle.apps.oic.integration.jetmapper.model.plugin.JETMapperAdapterV2.createJETMapperAdapter(JETMapperAdapterV2.java:552)
    at oracle.apps.oic.integration.jetmapper.model.plugin.JETMapperAdapterV2.createJETMapper(JETMapperAdapterV2.java:106)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.OrchestrationMapperUtils.createJetMapperAdapter(OrchestrationMapperUtils.java:211)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.OrchestrationMapperUtils.validateMapper(OrchestrationMapperUtils.java:231)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.TransformerElement.validateModel(TransformerElement.java:167)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.OrchestrationModelImpl.validateElements(OrchestrationModelImpl.java:1211)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.common.orchestrationmodel.OrchestrationModelImpl.updateElement(OrchestrationModelImpl.java:1190)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.view.beans.backing.orchestration.ReceiveBeanElement.updateElement(ReceiveBeanElement.java:390)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.view.beans.backing.composer.OrchestrationBean.onConfirmEditAdapter(OrchestrationBean.java:1655)
    at oracle.ics.webconsole.view.beans.backing.composer.OrchestrationPageBean.confirmEditAdapter(OrchestrationPageBean.java:1668)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6131.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3688)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1692)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1652)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: I don't think there is an error in your XSD file. What tool are you performing the validation with?

Comment: hmm, I tried validating that XSD with some online validator and it's totally correct. BTW, I send that XSD to Oracle Cloud Integration and it exposes the error. (see the image).

Comment: @kjhughes Long time indeed! Hope you are doing fine. @ NoName: Then that is an error on the part of Oracle, or perhaps you are not using the service as intended.

Comment: Agree with @MathiasMüller:  Since there is no problem at the XSD level, try redirecting your query to Oracle crowd who may be able to spot a common invocation/configuration issue.   It's also possible that the tool doesn't support all of XSD in performing its function, but it seems unlikely that it wouldn't support complex type content models.

Comment: ICS-10064 isn't in [Oracle Cloud: Error Messages for Oracle Integration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/error-messages/error-messages-oracle-integration.pdf)   Perhaps an update would help.

Comment: Added oracle-related tags per reasoning in above comments.

Comment: I have updated the error stack trace that I downloaded from OIC this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD as posted has no such error.   Suspect a mistake in how you're invoking validation.

`ICS-10064` isn't in [Oracle Cloud: Error Messages for Oracle Integration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/error-messages/error-messages-oracle-integration.pdf). If your invocation is correct, next try updating to see if an Oracle issue has been since resolved.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Oracle has confirmed this issue is a bug and they have fixed it recently.